# Additional CSS class not working with custom gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to add a new class with **Additional CSS class** in the custom WordPress Gutenberg block. It will add the class on change in editor side on the div but when I save and reload the page the **Additional CSS class** field will blank.

Here is my code

```
import classnames from "classnames";
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { Component, Fragment } from '@wordpress/element';

class edit extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super(...arguments);
    }

    render(){
        const { attributes, setAttributes, className } = this.props;
        const classes = classnames(
            className,
            'button-wrap'
        );
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className={classes}>
                    sdfsd
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

registerBlockType( 'gb/button', {
    title: __( 'Button' ),
    description: __( 'Button' ),
    icon: 'dashicons-admin-media',
    category: 'common',
    edit,
    save(props) {
        const { attributes, className } = props;
        const classes = classnames(
            className,
            'button-wrap'
        );
        
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className={classes}>
                    sdfsd
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
} );
```

Let me know if anyone has any ideas.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The function [useBlockProps()](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#block-wrapper-props) can add any additional classes in both `edit()` and `save()` functions.

In your code, add `import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor'` then replace:

```
const classes = classnames(
    className,
    'button-wrap'
);
...
<div className={classes}>sdfsd</div>
```

with:

```
const blockProps = useBlockProps( {
        className: 'button-wrap',
});
...
<div { ...blockProps }>sdfsd</div>
```

Comment: This works for me. I do not understand why it has not been marked as the answer unless @Sadik Multani needs and example of how the save.js function looks.